# Why is either Listable or HoldFirst not working?

Tags: function-construction, dynamic, pure-function, attributes

Starting with a fresh kernel, I evaluate the following:

```
Questions = {
    (* Statement, Answer, Incorrect Answer *)
    {"What is the capital of Switzerland?", "Bern", {"Vaduz", "Berlin", "Vienna"}},
    {"Who is the king of the jungle?", "Lion", {"Giraffe", "Mouse", "Monkey"}},
    {"2+2?" , "4", {"15", "13", "1e15"}}
} ;
Dynamic@Column@Questions

SetAttributes[DynamicInputField, {HoldFirst, Listable}];
DynamicInputField[var_, OptionsPattern[ContentType -> Expression]] := 
  InputField[Dynamic[var], OptionValue[ContentType], 
   ContinuousAction -> True, ImageSize -> Full];

Dynamic@Grid[{
   {"Statement", DynamicInputField[Questions[[1, 1]], ContentType -> String]},
   {"Answer", DynamicInputField[Questions[[1, 2]], ContentType -> String]},
   {Column[{"Incorrect Answers"}, BaselinePosition -> Top], 
    Column[DynamicInputField[#, ContentType -> String] & /@ Questions[[1, 3]],
        BaselinePosition -> Top]
   }
}, Alignment -> Left]
```

[image: Statement]

I must say that I took me a while to find out that I needed to set HoldFirst as an attribute for my function to work at least with the first two input fields. Nevertheless, the function does not work by mapping it into a list, i.e., the three last input fields send a error, the same one I had before I set HoldFirst as an attribute:

```
Set::setraw : Cannot assign to raw object Vaduz.>>
```

What am I doing wrong? I also tried the following:

```
Column[DynamicInputField[Questions[[1, 3]], ContentType -> String], 
    BaselinePosition -> Top]
```

[image: Attempt1]

```
Column[Table[
    DynamicInputField[Questions[[1, 3, n]], ContentType -> String], 
    {n, 3}], BaselinePosition -> Top]
```

[image: Attempt2]

Giving the errors:

```
Part::pkspec1 : The expression n cannot be used as a part specification.>>
```

even when I put the Table inside a `With[[n=n],...]`.

Moreover, why is not the same result in my two attempts of "solving" even though the function was set to be listable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Fundamental problem

Pardon me if I miss some points of your question as I didn't attempt to understand what your code is intended to do, because I think I understand what the problem is from the title alone.  Please consider:

```
SetAttributes[f, {HoldFirst, Listable}];

f[x_] := foo[x]

f[{1, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {foo[1], foo[2], foo[3]}
> ```

```
bar = {1, 2, 3};
f[bar]
```

> ```
> foo[{1, 2, 3}]
> ```

`Listable` can only work across lists that it can "see" and `HoldFirst` prevents `bar` from evaluating to an explicit list.

---

#### Analysis of attempts

Your first attempt: `Column[DynamicInputField[ . . .` fails because the expression returned by `DynamicInputField` is not a `List` but an `InputField`, therefore `Column` has nothing to format.

Your second attempt is *almost* correct except that `n` is not evaluated (because of `HoldFirst`).
It *will* work if you put the `With` *inside* the `Table`:

```
Column[Table[
  With[{n = n}, DynamicInputField[Questions[[1, 3, n]], ContentType -> String]], {n, 3}], 
 BaselinePosition -> Top]
```

It would be simpler however to use [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Array.html).  (See below.)

---

#### Proposed solution

I believe this will work as you require.

```
ClearAll[DynamicInputField]
SetAttributes[DynamicInputField, {HoldFirst, Listable}];

DynamicInputField[var_, opts___] /; ListQ[var] := 
  Column @ Array[DynamicInputField[var[[#]], opts] &, Length @ var]

DynamicInputField[var_, OptionsPattern[ContentType -> Expression]] := 
  InputField[Dynamic[var], OptionValue[ContentType], ContinuousAction -> True, 
   ImageSize -> Full];
```

Test:

```
DynamicInputField[Questions[[1, 3]], ContentType -> String]
```

[image]

Also:

```
DynamicInputField[Questions[[1]], ContentType -> String]
```

[image]

Comment: Specifically, I would like that `DynamicInputFiled` worked by giving it either a variable like `Question[[1,1]]` or by giving it a list such as `Question[[1,3]]` by giving me a `FieldInput` as defined or a list of those.

I didn't know what you mentioned above about how Listable "sees". That might be the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: @Carlos Okay, I actually read your code this time.  I believe that this is indeed the problem, but I don't see a simple solution because of the way this is written.  Let me think about this.

Comment: Thanks. And by giving it a second though, I don't actually need that the function can handle either an expression or a list - by being able to map it to a list should do (I tried that but didn't work either).

Comment: As suggested by @Mr.Wizard, removing `HoldFirst` and then just using `Column[DynamicInputField[Questions[[1, 3]], ContentType -> String], BaselinePosition -> Top]` works for me.

Comment: @Carlos Please see my extended answer.

Comment: @caya I'm afraid that doesn't work; try typing something into the input fields.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I see!

Comment: Yes, @caya in an attempt that I didn't upload I tried that. 
And the proposed extended solution worked. Thank you so much for your quick and extensive help.

Comment: @Carlos You're welcome.  I'm glad I could help. :-)